# Undefined Value Returned for Text Input and Display YQL Query Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yql

I am trying to display content from a YQL Query. However, the value I am entering into my text field is returning a value of **undefined** when I submit it, thus causing the YQL query to fail.

Along with this issue, I'm not sure how to select just the titles from the data argument in the callback function for the getJSON function in this portion of my code:

```
//Return the JSON results of the YQL query
$.getJSON(restQuery, function(data) {
    //Display the returned results in the searchResults div
    $("#searchResults").html(data);
});
```

**Here is the JSFiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/JAS4H/30/**

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned up your code a bit.

```
$(function() {

    function search(term) {
        var query = 'SELECT title FROM search.web WHERE query="' + term + '"',
            url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc';

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#searchResults').html(data);
        });
    }

    $('#search').live('submit', function() {
        search($('#searchInput').val());
        return false;
    });

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAS4H/33/

As you can see, the response data is not JSON - that's why $.getJSON() does not work. For instance, if you search for "cars", you will get this response:

> cbfunc({"query":{"count":10,"created":"2011-02-21T20:40:16Z","lang":"en-US","diagnostics":{"publiclyCallable":"true","url":{"execution-time":"779","content":"http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/cars?format=xml&start=0&count=10"},"user-time":"781","service-time":"779","build-version":"11323"},"results":{"result":[{"title":"New
>   & Used Cars for Sale, Auto Dealers,
>   Car Reviews and Car
>   ..."},{"title":"Cars
>   (Movie)"},{"title":"AutoTrader"},{"title":"New
>   Cars, Used Cars, Blue Book Values &
>   Car Prices - Kelley
>   ..."},{"title":"Automobile -
>   Wikipedia, the free
>   encyclopedia"},{"title":"Car Allowance
>   Rebate System (CARS)"},{"title":"Used
>   Cars - Used Car Prices, Used Car
>   Values & Reviews
>   ..."},{"title":"Edmunds.com"},{"title":"Cars
>   For Sale, Used Cars For Sale, New Cars
>   For Sale ..."},{"title":"Research New
>   Cars & Used Cars : Automobile Prices,
>   Specs ..."}]}}});

This is JSONP I believe ...

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I didn't notice that you had already updated it. That fixed the undefined issue, but do you also know how I could display the YQL results? If you are not sure how to solve my YQL issues, I will still accept you answer as the correct one when I am able because you did fix the undefined issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Šime Vidas! If you know how I might solve my YQL issues, feel free to let me know! Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, sorry again that I didn't notice you updated your answer. Thank you for pointing out that it is not JSON. I suppose I will have to try to learn how to extract values from JSONP now. Thanks for all your help @Šime Vidas!